# Using a Domain Name to Run a Python Script

Tags: python, server, domain-name

This question isn't related to some specific code, but rather implementation:

This may seem like a dumb question but does anyone know how to use a domain name to host a python script that runs continuously? Some examples of how this would be used: as a script that handles data or a server for a game. If this is unreasonable, is there some other way to have a python script run continuously online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the script at [Link1](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) or if you want to run it on your machine, you can create a page and put the script there can be with flask (and integrate it with flask) and mount it on a server and do not put it as a website with graphics but as a website that runs it [Link2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu%20-18-04).